# Equivalence of two POVMs in continuous variable system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, quantum-measurements

In continuous variable systems, the Gaussian POVM is generally defined as [see e.g. Eq. ($1$) of this [article]](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2799)

\begin{equation}
\Pi_j(\alpha_j) = \frac{1}{\pi} D_{j}(\alpha_j) \Pi_j^0 D_{j}^\dagger(\alpha_j)
\end{equation}
where $D_j(\alpha_j)$ is the displacement operator and $\Pi^0_j$ is a density matrix.  Now, there is another definition given in Eq. ($30$) [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.02098)

$$M_{a|s} = \int \frac{d^{2m}y}{(2\pi)^{2m}} D(y) e^{-y^T \sigma_s^M y/2 -a^T \Omega y}$$
where now, $a$ is the measurement outcome, $s$ labels the $s$-$th$ POVM element, $D(y)$ is the displacement operator, and $y$  a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$ ($m$ being the number of field modes).

My question is, if these two definitions are equivalent (which I suppose they should) then how to prove this equivalence?